# Play Bansuri WITHOUT Person in Next Room Knowing

Tags: noise, bansuri, soundproofing

I took up Bansuri practice again and it disturbs the person in the next room.

How do I play Bansuri so that the person in the next room doesn't even know I am playing?

I am unable to find a muter for Bansuri, i.e Bamboo flute. And I cannot afford to purchase Sandbag partitions.

I was thinking of getting under heavy quilts and comforters and then playing, but Summer is around the corner. Won't it get hot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a Soundproof Room](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9609/making-a-soundproof-room)

Comment: @Aaron how do I mute a Bansuri, i.e. Bamboo flute. I searched Amazon for sand-filled partition and they are pricey!

Comment: To the best of my understanding, the instrument itself cannot be muted. However, this site contains many suggestions for using room furnishings like rugs or curtains, as well as other, cheaper soundproofing materials, to help absorb sound. I suggest you search for "soundproof", "soundproofing", and [tag:soundproofing].

Answer (score 2):

The heavy quilts sound your best bet.  Yes, it will probably get hot.  The classic impromptu isolation booth is a cubicle built from duvets over a clothes drier frame.

BTW, This isn't an isolation booth.

[image]

This is.

[image]

Comment: yeah, I see isolaton booths on Amazon and it looks like it is for microphone, not to play into a 24" bansuri https://www.amazon.com/s?k=impromptu+isolation+booth&ref=nb_sb_noss

Answer (score 2):

Since there seems to be no method to mute a bansuri, then playing under a duvet is a poor option. Heat, lack of air are two factors not in its favour. Often bathrooms are next to each other in flats, etc, so playing in a little used room next to another little used room may help.

If not, distance works well: if you drive and have a car, gett out in that and play. If not, get out into an area where you can play alone, or with only dog-walkers to upset.

Comment: I am unable to leave my apartment (COVID lockdown). Even then I live in high-crime area :-(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Only other solution - buy the offended person some ear defenders, or noise-cancelling earphones.